# Pinning Feet Not Working: Adobe Character Animator

Tags: animation, adobe-character-animator

I've created a character, and I spent a great deal of time (a couple hours) working on him. After importing him into Adobe Ch Animator as a puppet, I try and pin his feet down with the pinning tool so that the whole character doesn't move when I use motion capture on his face. Well, after going into record mode, the character's whole body still moves, along with his feet. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is it a bug, or is it a problem with my character rig? Any help would be mush appreciated.